# Install Xcode 10.1 on Old Macbook

Tags: macos, mac, macbook-pro, xcode

I have a mid-2010 Macbook Pro running OS X 10.8.5. For one of my classes, I must use the current version of Xcode, being 10.1. Unfortunately, my Macbook is not compatible with the OS necessary to install the current version. Is there any way for me to get it on my Macbook?

Comment: Can you run a virtual machine?

Comment: Min reqs for Xcode 10.1 is High Sierra... Max OS for that machine is... High Sierra.